# React CRA with typescript not working with eslint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am trying to integrate linting into an app created using CRA which uses typescript.

Steps to reproduce on terminal

- `create-react-app my-app --typescript`
- `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init`

  - select : To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style
  - select : JavaScript modules (import/export)
  - select : React
  - y for does your project use typescript
  - select : Browser
  - Popular style guide used is airbnb

My .eslintrc json file looks like the following

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "semi":"warn"
    }
}
```

I usually check if the lint works by removing semi colon to see if vs code highlights.

However it does not happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following snippet to settings.json on VS code works.

```
"eslint.validate": [
  "javascript",
  "javascriptreact",
  "typescript",
  "typescriptreact"
],
```

Comment: You don't have to set autoFix, it's now deprecated and set as default

Comment: Thanks, I did that change.

Comment: better to use just strings instead of object? :P not `{"language": "typescript"}` but just "typescript" and so on.

Answer (score -1):

There are **two** types of setting ESLint in React CRA.

1. Local ESLint (Only affect the Editor such as VSCode)
2. ESLint when Compiling (When running `yarn start` and saving file)

As there are too much (not needed) information on the internet, I created an article about this in a much simpler way in [here](https://medium.com/@michael.tandio/using-create-react-app-typescript-with-custom-eslint-rules-5fc5aec3ff10).